# Error compiling sqlite in qmake project

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qmake

Long time ago I added sqlite3.c file to my qmake project and successfully compiled this project for months using msvc-2013 and gcc-5.2 64 bit compilers.

However when I tried to recompile this project recently it compiles all files successfully but sqlite3.c file!!! and it gives me strange error messages:

*cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zi -MDd -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 /Fddebug\Builder3d.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DVL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS=1 -DVL_OPENGL=1 -D_UNICODE=1 -DNOMINMAX -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPROTOBUF_USE_DLLS -DB3D_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_WEBSOCKETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Builder3d -I. -I..\libs\c3d\v98099\Win64_Visual_Studio_2013_Unicode\Include -I..\libs -I..\libs\protobuf\cmake\build\debug\include -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtSql -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWebSockets -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtNetwork -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -ID:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Rem\AppData\Local\Temp\sqlite3.obj.20112.0.jom
sqlite3.c*

**D:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qnamespace.h(53): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'**

**D:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qnamespace.h(68): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Qt'**

**D:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qnamespace.h(68): error C2059: syntax error: ';'**

**D:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qnamespace.h(68): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)**

So when compiling sqlite3.c it gives me tons of errors from qt libraries despite the fact sqlite3.c do not include any of them!!!

PS: The only change in my computer configuration that I can think of is update to MSVC compiler toolchain after installing VS update.

PPS: My project was configured to use msvc2013 & Qt 5.5. After the error I tried to use msvc2015 & Qt 5.7  but the problem persists.

Comment: Are you using the `extern` keyword to include sqlite.c to your project.

Comment: No, I added sqlite3.c to SOURCES in qmake file and include sqlite3.h in other files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can be sure that what happened is the "crossing" of includes.

From what you listed, the compilation of sqlite3.c happens with a lot of "-Ipath_to_qt", so include paths to qt headers are propagated.

Then, for example, sqlite3.c includes config.h to read options how sqlite should be configured. Sure there is another config.h coming from some qt include folder and this config.h brings references/subincludes to qt.

Comment: I see. There are two questions: why did it used to compile successfully and how to fix it?

Comment: Simply new Qt 5.5 now have for example this config.h somewhere while previous version didn't have

Comment: Try just to comment #include config.h

Comment: Copy-paste command line to compile sqlite3.c to console, remove all -I to Qt and try to compile. Just as test to see that it is coming from there.

Comment: It's really hard to change sqlite3.h as its kind of bundle made by SqLite team from all sources. Is it possible to configure qmake do not add include paths to particular file?

Comment: qmake does not allow to do it per file as I remember. What you can do is to make sub-project qmake project which have CONFIG -= qt and it does make only mysquite.lib which is used in your main project.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't helped me. But I found another problem: if I comment sqlite3.c from project It compile successfully but gives strange warning: Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

Comment: Even strange if I create an empty project, copy-paste all configs and libraries from the original one and add sqlite3.c - it also compiles succefully!!!